# How to change length of one plot in subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

How to change the length of one plot in a subplot?

It may be a simple problem but I have difficulty solving this.

To represent the result of signal analysis, I represented three plots in a subplot.

But, because the third graph had a colorbar,   only this is short.

How can I solve this problem?

- I added some parts that draw each plot in a subplot in my code except detail.
- To avoid misunderstanding, I added figure.
  [In the below figure, the length of the spectrogram plot in the python figure(left) is shorter than the above two plots. But the length of the spectrogram plot in the Matlab figure(right) is equal to the above plots. How can make the length of the third plot be equal with the above plots, like the result of Matlab?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC9z0.jpg)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, cbar) = plt.subplots(3, 2)
ax1.plot(sb['Seconds'], sb['Real'], 'dodgerblue', linewidth = 0.5)
ax2.plot(f2, np.log(P3), 'k', linewidth = 0.5)
s, freqs, bins, im = ax3.specgram(y, NFFT = N, Fs=Fs1,  cmap='jet')
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax3, orientation = 'vertical', pad = 0.009)
```

Comment: Use constrained_layout=True in the subplots command.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the figure object use:

```
f.set_figheight(15)
f.set_figwidth(15)
```

But if you use the .subplots() command (as in the examples you're showing) to create a new figure you can also use:

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(15,15))
```

For example: -
Alternatively, create a figure() object using the figsize argument and then use add_subplot to add your subplots. E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
ax = f.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(122)
x = np.linspace(0,4,1000)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ax2.plot(x, np.cos(x), 'r:')
```

Benefits of this method are that the syntax is closer to calls of subplot() instead of subplots(). E.g. subplots doesn't seem to support using a GridSpec for controlling the spacing of the subplots, but both subplot() and add_subplot() do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, because I have more questions, so I added questions and figure images.